# addPostFrameCallback can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null' in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I got a trouble but can't solve. I have this code

```
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => yourFunction(context));
  }
```

And I got

`The method 'addPostFrameCallback' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'. Try making the call conditional (using '?.') or adding a null check to the target ('!').`

Why and How can I fix that ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[`WidgetsBinding.instance`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WidgetsBinding/instance.html) is not always initialized. `runApp` will do this for you so you only have to worry about it not being initialized if you're doing something outside of `runApp`, which you're not doing here.

In the relatively recent migration to [null-safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety) they made `WidgetsBinding.instance` nullable as it's possible that it will not be initialized, evident from the `?` at the end of it's type.

The solution is in your error message. Use either the bang operator `!` or the conditional call operator `?.`. The former will tell the compiler that you *know* that `WidgetsBinding.instance` will not be `null` when it's used and throw an exception if you're wrong. The latter will do nothing if it's `null`.

I would recommend using the former, the `!` operator, as it's expected that `WidgetsBinding.instance` will never be `null` when you use it here and it may help find bugs down the line.

---

Examples:

Bang operator `!`:

```dart
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) => yourFunction(context));
}
```

Conditional call `?.`:

```dart
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  WidgetsBinding.instance?.addPostFrameCallback((_) => yourFunction(context));
}
```

Comment: i dont've the code & i got problem its reference from package , so how to solve ? ```: Error: Method 'addPostFrameCallback' cannot be called on 'WidgetsBinding?' because it is potentially null.
../…/widgets/auto_route_navigator.dart:47
- 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('../../../../../dev/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
package:flutter/…/widgets/binding.dart:1
    Try calling using ?. instead.
          WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^```