# Syncfusion flutter calendar view Error: Method 'addPostFrameCallback' cannot be called on 'SchedulerBinding?'

Tags: flutter, syncfusion

Syncfusion flutter calendar view this error:

```
  /E:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/syncfusion_flutter_calendar-20.1.59/lib/src/calendar/views/calendar_view.dart:3871:35: Error: Method 'addPostFrameCallback' cannot be called on 'SchedulerBinding?' because it is potentially null.
    - 'SchedulerBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart' ('/E:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/scheduler/binding.dart').
    package:flutter/…/scheduler/binding.dart:1
    Try calling using ?. instead.
    /E:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/syncfusion_flutter_calendar-20.1.59/lib/src/calendar/views/calendar_view.dart:8613:13: Error: No named parameter with the name 'thumbVisibility'.
                thumbVisibility: !widget.isMobilePlatform,
```

And this is my container widget:

```
Container(
                  child: SfCalendar(),
                ),
```

Please help me to find out what’s wrong.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It happens in null-safety properties at the last upgrade of `Flutter 3.0.0`. There are some solutions in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72247146/11675817).

You can try it.

Answer (score 0):

When migrating to Flutter 3, the warning like Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'SchedulerBinding' which excludes null. These warnings are caused by the instance property on bindings is now non-nullable. So, no need to specify the null-aware operators such as (! and ?). Kindly, migrate SfCalendar(above 20.1.56) and Flutter (3.0.0) to latest version resolving this error.

Kindly find the release notes for the same by referring to the following link,

https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/sdk/release-notes/release-notes-3.0.0#if-you-see-warnings-about-bindings